# Ender 3 Won't Print Small/Thinner Items

Tags: creality-ender-3, filament

Pretty new to 3d Printing. Ultimaker Cura as my Slicer. I have the Ender3 3d Printer.

I have a model from Hero Forge I'm trying to print. I added some caltrops on the base but when I go to print the figure, my Ender3 won't finish the caltrops/smaller items and won't finish the figure. It will basically just go through the motions lol.

Here's an example of it happening on the base of my Figure.

This is the mockup and afterwards is basically where it stops and the filament either just stops coming out or the nozzle moves around the filament that actually does print.

[image]

[image]

Here's an example of something similar happening to Pikachu's ears.
[image]

Comment: There are several issues with your printer. If that is the top layer of the base we see, your printer is extremely under extruding. The problems with the bottom image are not related, there you have retraction issues and too fast printing of the small area layers in the right ear, hot on hot equals molten mess. It is better to split the question in two separate questions.

Comment: What is your retraction length and speed? And what speed and layer height are you printing at? Unfortunately, this looks pretty much like what I'd expect for an Ender 3 with the stock extruder. It should be possible to get it "better", so it doesn't stop extruding completely like this, but I was never able to get prints I'd call good, with extrusion solid enough not to be brittle, using it.

Comment: Looks like there is too much stringing and globs. As @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE said, please provide us with some more information. Maybe even noxxle temp. and units that the model was shown in (on the software)

Answer (score 2):

### Resolution is limited

You are printing with FDM. FDM is limited in printing detail by its nozzle diameter: you can not print something that is much smaller than your nozzle diameter. A typical nozzle is 0.4 mm in diameter. Your figurine? That is too thin and fragile.

Comment: Might suggest to use a resin printer if it is just stuff for display that isn't meant to be functionable.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try again with another filament. It looks like your nozzle is either clogging or your filament is slipping. There could be multiple reasons why, but the easiest first troubleshooting strategy is to change filament because it can rule out half the reasons.